# how to collect the information provided by tokens in order to troubleshoot failing jobs quickly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, jobs, database-mail

I was working on a way to take advantage of [the SQL Server Agent Tokens and Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-2017#sql-server-agent-tokens-and-macros) because I work a lot with [jobs and job steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-2017#sql-server-agent-tokens-and-macros) and sometimes I have to notify different people depending on the outcome of the job.

For example some people want to make sure that the job has run, if there is a problem, some other people and the DBAs should be notified and so on.

I have been using [the SQL Server Agent Tokens and Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-2017#sql-server-agent-tokens-and-macros) to add information to my failing jobs email notifications, but they don't seem to be working fine as I will show you on the example below.

A job with 4 steps - the last one is the checking on, it fails on step 02 - I have done a division by zero there.

[image]

But when I get the email I get something like this:

[image]

this is the code on step 04 - the checking step:

```
--exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name='radhe'
--exec sp_getjobhistory @job_name='radhe'



DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2);
DECLARE @email nvarchar(1008);
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Title NVARCHAR(504);

SELECT @CRLF=CHAR(10)+CHAR(13);

SELECT @email = 'mmiorelli@MYCOMPANY.COM';

SELECT @title = 'the job called: ' +
                             '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))' + 
                             ' --  failed  -- ' + 
                            '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(DATE))'  + 
                            ' - ' +  
                            '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(TIME))'


SELECT @body = @title + @CRLF + @CRLF + @CRLF +
              'Computer name. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(MACH))' + @CRLF + 
              'Server name. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-SVR))' + @CRLF + 
              'Name of the computer running SQL Server. If the SQL Server instance is a named instance, this includes the instance name. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR))' + @CRLF + 
              'Instance name. For a default instance, this token will have the default instance name: MSSQLSERVER. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(INST))' + @CRLF + 
              'Database name. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-DBN))' + @CRLF + 
              'Error number. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-ERR))' + @CRLF + 
              'Error severity. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-SEV))' + @CRLF + 
              'Message text.  ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-MSG))' + @CRLF + 
              'Job ID. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))' + @CRLF + 
              'Step ID. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))' + @CRLF + 
              'The name of the job. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))' + @CRLF + 
              'The name of the step. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPNAME))' + @CRLF + 
              'Current date (in YYYYMMDD format). ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(DATE))' + @CRLF + 
              'Current time (in HHMMSS format). ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(TIME))' + @CRLF + 
              'Master SQLServerAgent service name. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(MSSA))' + @CRLF + 
              'The directory in which SQL Server is installed. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLDIR))' + @CRLF + 
              'Prefix for the program used to run CmdExec job steps. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(OSCMD))' + @CRLF + 
              'A count of the number of times this step has executed (excluding retries). ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPCT))' + @CRLF + 
              'Replacement token for the SQL Server error log folder path - for example, $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR)). ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))' + @CRLF + 
              'The date (in YYYYMMDD format) that the job began executing. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))' + @CRLF + 
              'The time (in HHMMSS format) that the job began executing. ' + '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM))' + @CRLF + @CRLF 


               -- EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@email,  -- Add Valid Email Id
               -- @subject = @title,
               -- @profile_name = 'DBA', -- Change Profile Name
               -- @body = @body,
               -- @body_format = 'TEXT' ;



SELECT  step_name, message
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE   instance_id > COALESCE((SELECT MAX(instance_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
                                WHERE job_id = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID)) AND step_id = 0), 0)
        AND job_id = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))
        AND run_status <> 1 -- success

IF      @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN 


                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@email,  -- Add Valid Email Id
                @subject = @title,
                @profile_name = 'DBA', -- Change Profile Name
                @body = @body,
                @body_format = 'TEXT' ;   -- 'HTML' ;

                RAISERROR('Ooops, the job failed!  ', 16, 1)

END
```

question:
any suggestions as how I can make this work as expected?

Expected means collecting information and added that info in the body of the email to be sent when the job fails.

the information would be those advertised by the tokens.

Comment: the info seems to be related to the current step id, which has no error, therefor no error message

Comment: You most likely have to grab whatever info you need from the jobhistory table in msdb. I've written a procedure that send email and attach output files based on job outcome. I.e., it has code to do pretty much of what you want to do, I suggest you use that and modify it to suit your needs... https://karaszi.com/mailafterjob-send-email-after-agent-job-include-ouput-files